# Read .json file line by line

Tags: node.js

I have a json file with json objects in it, please how can I read the json objects line by line. Is this the best way to read a json file using node.js, pardon my question, just a node.js newbie

My json file simply contains lines of json objects as:

```
file.json
{"name":"user1"},
{"name":"user2"},
{"name":"user3"}
```

and I am trying to read the file with

```
app.get('/s',function(req,res){
  var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/file.json';


    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
      }

      data = JSON.parse(data);

      console.dir(data);
    });
    });
```

I get an error with that code that says "unexpected token {" just on the second line", tanks

//EDIT
It turned out my Json file was invalid because readFile reads the entire file, I changed it by putting the objects in an array:

```
file.json
[
{"name":"user1"},
{"name":"user2"},
{"name":"user3"}
]
```

Then this code reads the entire file (array)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/file.json';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  data.forEach(function(user){ 
    console.log(user.name);
  })

});
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. `readFile` reads the entire file. If you want valid JSON you need to wrap your list with `[]` `[{"name":"user1"},{"name":"user2"},{"name":"user3"}]`

Comment: I edited the question and answered it there (rep<10) thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about invalid json

Answer (score 6):

Node's built-in `require` function can read JSON and convert it to an object (or array) for you automatically, so all you need is:

```
var users = require(__dirname + '/file.json');
```

Also FYI the filename extension is optional, so you don't necessarily have to know or care if this is `.js`, `.json` or any other extension that node may learn to load in the future.

Comment: I am not sure this is a good answer, in that for the original content, there were no `[`, and `]`. Practically, as for many jsons in data analysis, each line contains a different JSON object, and `require` does not understand this